# Unable to get the freemarker template working on restlet, protocol used is not declared in the client connectors

Tags: java, freemarker, restlet

I'm trying to pass in the location of my ftl template.

In MyApplication extend Application

I've tried....

```
getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.FILE);
```

I even tried this out of disperation...

```
ConnectorService cs =new ConnectorService();
    cs.setClientProtocols(UtilMisc.toList(Protocol.FILE, Protocol.HTTP));
    setConnectorService(cs);

@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    //I even added this in to get it to print out which had been set and they were in there!
    for(Protocol p :getConnectorService().getClientProtocols()){
        Debug.log(p.getName());
    }

    // initialize the Freemarker's configuration
    configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration
            .setTemplateLoader(new ContextTemplateLoader(
                    getContext(),
                    "file:/D:/development/myexample/deploy/myexample-integrations/webapp/myexample-base/service"));
```

Then I have this in my HtmlRepresentationHandler.....

```
    String templateName = "serviceInfo.ftl";
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML;
    TemplateRepresentationrep = new TemplateRepresentation(templateName, getApp().getConfiguration(), cleanServiceResultMapInstance(results), mediaType);
```

I always get the same error, I even tried other protocols to no avail.

```
Jan 8, 2012 4:45:58 AM org.restlet.engine.component.ClientRouter getNext
 [java] WARNING: The protocol used by this request is not declared in the list of client connectors. (FILE)
 [java] WARNING: Unable to get the template serviceInfo.ftl. Error message: Template serviceInfo.ftl not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember fighting this too [here](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=2862279).

The solution is finally to declare the client protocol in the servlet paramaeters for the application :

```
  <servlet>
                 <init-param>
                         <param-name>or​g.restlet.clients​</param-name>
                         <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
                 </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

see also the [javadoc](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/gae/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html)